# How to make M2Crypto work with aes128-cbc-pkcs7?

Tags: python, cryptography, pycrypto, m2crypto

In Python script I need to decrypt data encrypted by aes128-cbc-pkcs7

I checked example in [Problem with M2Crypto's AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003626/problem-with-m2cryptos-aes) answer, but it describes aes128-cbc and I have no idea how to adopt it for aes128-cbc-pkcs7

All I have is a key:

```
key = 'MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgHdH2zoKQJ43olhVZstEiBHjZvhUkGL1YcB2baSlHsHjoV5uRkYDyPEHUaN7htski3aGoIUY1vEF7nv0dJaM686KqEfkIxzlRizdnNJr+A8j1OOnOPOooqTuf06570kEEqXCW2STlLIMxwIESPHXAqiKYMPUtNGfu+PpmdY6NUHDAgMBAAE='
```

or

```
    key = """MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgHdH2zoKQJ43olhVZstEiBHjZvhU
kGL1YcB2baSlHsHjoV5uRkYDyPEHUaN7htski3aGoIUY1vEF7nv0dJaM686KqEfk
IxzlRizdnNJr+A8j1OOnOPOooqTuf06570kEEqXCW2STlLIMxwIESPHXAqiKYMPU
tNGfu+PpmdY6NUHDAgMBAAE="""
```

I'm not sure how to store the key in a right way - with line brakes or without.

Can you please provide some example how to use aes128-cbc-pkcs7 to encode/decode that should be similar to aes128-cbc (explained in [Problem with M2Crypto's AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003626/problem-with-m2cryptos-aes))

Sorry if questions sounds strange, I'm total newbie in cryptography.

Comment: First of all, you need to talk to the person that created the ciphertext and explain to him that you require much more information about the used protocol. You need to know encoding, character-encoding, IV handling etc. etc. before you can encrypt any data. Just trying willy-nilly will not end well. Get a formalized description of the protocol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use encrypt using just AES if you've been given an RSA public key. You need to use hybrid encryption: generate a random AES key of 16, 24 or 32 bytes, then encrypt. You can keep to a zero IV if you generate a new AES key for each encryption.

The AES key itself can then be encrypted using the public key you've been given, using either [OAEP](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP-module.html) or - for backwards compatibility - [PKCS#1 v1.5 padding](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html).

The default module does not seem to use padding, if I read the documentation correctly. I've found a padding/unpadding routine on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zi11rc8h), thanks go to Peter for sharing:

```
def pkcs7_pad(data, blocksize=16):
    padlen = blocksize - len(data) % blocksize
    return data + bytes([padlen]) * padlen


def pkcs7_unpad(data, blocksize=16):
    if data:
        padlen = data[-1]
        if 0 < padlen < blocksize:
            if data.endswith(bytes([padlen]) * padlen):
                return data[:-padlen]

    raise ValueError('incorrect padding')
```

---

Note that just encryption is not secure if you are using this over a communication channel. It is required to add a message authentication code (MAC), even if you just require confidentiality of the plaintext. Incorrect use of CBC mode encryption may make the protocol vulnerable to padding oracle attacks.

Comment: Your last sentence is quite misleading. The questions is about AES128-CBC, which is just a cipher and still safe to use. Oracle attack cannot be interpreted in context of the cipher.
There are protocols (e.g. certain versions of TLS) provide the oracle which can be used for that attack, thus those protocols are vulnerable. However, that is a weakness of that given protocol, it has nothing to do with cipher, which is still safe when it is being used correctly.

Comment: @bakcsa83 Right, slightly modified the answer to take this into account. I think given the question (two different runtimes, self-written unpadding routine) that a warning is certainly in order; the specifics of the attacks are something that the reader has to consider him/herself.